# How to upload multiple files into cowboy

Tags: erlang, multipartform-data, cowboy

trying to upload files using curl

```
curl -v -F 'file1=@/home/user/test/aaa/validation_utils.erl' -F 'file2=@/home/user/test/aaa/README.md' http://localhost:8083/api/list
```

but receiving only one (as i can see from logs)

```
[warning] Form_Data:
[{<<"content-type">>,<<"application/octet-stream">>},{<<"content-disposition">>,<<"form-data; name=\"file1\"; filename=\"validation_utils.erl\"">>}]
```

this is my get_body function:

```
get_body(<<"POST">>, AllHeaders, Req, _MaxFileSize) ->
  case maps:get(<<"content-type">>, AllHeaders) of
    <<"application/json", _Rest/binary>> ->
      case catch cowboy_req:read_body(Req) of
        {ok, <<>>, Req2} ->
          {ok, [], Req2};
        {ok, JsonBody, Req2} when JsonBody =/= <<>> ->
          try
            {ok, ?JSON_DECODE(JsonBody), Req2}
          catch
            _:Err ->
              Err
          end
      end;
    <<"multipart/form-data", _Rest/binary>> ->
      {ok, Headers, Req2} = cowboy_req:read_part(Req),
      {ok, Data, _Req3} = cowboy_req:read_part_body(Req2),
      {file, _, Filename, _ContentType, _BitSize} = cow_multipart:form_data(Headers),
      Body = [{<<"filename">>, Filename}, {<<"base64_file">>, base64:encode(Data)} | cowboy_req:parse_qs(Req)],
      {ok, Body, Req};
    _ ->
      cowboy_req:read_urlencoded_body(Req)
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

I need to iterate the `cowboy_req:read_part(Req)`

```
multipart(Req0) ->
  case cowboy_req:read_part(Req0) of
    {ok, Headers, Req1} ->
      ?LOG_WARNING("Headers: p~n", [Headers]),
      {ok, _Body, Req} = cowboy_req:read_part_body(Req1),
      multipart(Req);
    {done, Req} ->
      ?LOG_WARNING("Req: p~n", [Req]),
      Req
  end.
```

as mentioned here : https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/multipart/